# Which is correct - "while chapaties are being made" or "while making chapaties"?

Tags: passive-voice

I have to change the voice of the following sentence

> Our mothers use tongs while making chapaties.

I think its answer would be

> Tongs are used by our mothers while chapaties are being made.

But the answer in my book is

> Tongs are used by our mothers while making chapaties.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but I think the book's version is preferable simply because it's more concise and less clunky.

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=making+tea%2Ctea+is+being+made%2C+making+cookies%2C+cookies+are+being+made&year_start=1950&year_end=2000) makes it pretty clear which version you'd be more likely to encounter in published books.